# "Failed to enable constraints" error message in sql query from c#

Tags: sql, dataset, runtime-error, constraints

I'm using C# and SQL in Visual Web Developer 2010 express.

I realize that my problem is with the ENFORCECONSTRAINTS property - which I cannot figure out how to modify.  I see no options for doing this in the query designer window.  I tried modifying every instance of it to false in the designer.cs file.  Doesn't work.

I have the following query which works when I run it from the query editor. It returns exactly one row, as it should, and that row is the correct row.

```
SELECT  
    A.*, B.*
FROM
    tblParticipants AS A 
INNER JOIN
    tblAdministrators AS B ON A.Part_Department = B.Adm_Department
WHERE        
    (A.Part_UserID = @UID) AND (B.Adm_POC = 'Y')
```

I invoke this query from code as:

```
    tblCertApplicationsTableAdapter certAdapter = new tblCertApplicationsTableAdapter();

    DataTable certTable = certAdapter.GetAdmContactByUID(iUserID);
```

When I execute this query from code, it tells me:

> Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Even though it works exactly correctly when I use the query window (returning exactly 1 correct record).

I display `iUserID` right before I execute those commands, so the right number is being passed.

Both tables, A and B, have a key column which does not accept nulls.

All other columns accept nulls. Since all the columns are set to allow nulls, I don't think that part of the error message makes sense. I tried just listing the columns I need - which does not include either of the respective key columns, so I don't think a non-unique key is the problem.

Is there a way to tell VWD - "Look, I know you think you know what's going on, but just please, dear god, return what you have and let me sort it out?"

Answer (score 0):

The message is coming from the `TableAdapter`, not from SQL Server. Your strongly-typed `DataSet` has its own constraint system that can enforce things like nullability and relationships. I would suspect that one or more of those columns that are nullable in the database are marked as not nullable in the `DataSet`. You can either change that or simply disable constraint checking on the `DataTable` altogether by setting `EnforceConstraints` in the designer to `False`.

Comment: I'm not explicitly using any DataSets, so I infer from what you wrote that vwd somehow translates from an adapter to dataset on the way to making a DataTable - so I don't know how to "change that." ("that" being something I wasn't even aware I was using.)  I don't see anything in the designer that allows me to change or even view the parameter EnforceConstraints. I check properties on the adapter, on my xsd file, and on the specific query.

Comment: `TableAdapter`s always use datasets; the file that you're designing *is* a strongly-typed `DataSet`, and you're creating `TableAdapter`-derived classes with the columns. These create strongly-typed `DataTable`s. If you look at the return type for `GetAdmContactByUID`, it's probably `tblCertApplicationsDataTable`. Just go into the designer where the adapter is, select the gray area, and disable "Enforce Constraints".

Comment: Adam Robinson I am having the same problem and setting EnforceConstraints to false did not work.

Comment: @MichaelS.Miller It's probably best if you post a new question; diagnosing your problem in the comments would be difficult and make it harder for users experiencing your problem to find a solution. Feel free to post a link to it, though, and I'll have a look!